# Конфигурирование плагина MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Подскажите, может ли хост при загрузке плагина передать в него какую-то информацию или при создании используется только конструктор по умолчанию?

Если нельзя, то какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: А почему бы не сделать плагину метод для передачи тех же самых параметров и самому не вызвать?

Comment: @Monk, на мой взгляд, пострадает инкапсуляция. Получается, что внешний компонент знает об устройстве плагина то, что перед использованием нужно вызвать спец метод, а конструктор как раз более лучшее решение.

Comment: Если это объявлено в самом интерфейсе плагина - нет в этом проблемы. Всё равно, обычно нужно единичное событие ДО использования плагина, чтобы он мог себя привести в рабочее состояние. Если в вашем случае это не так - ну тогда не подходит, да.

Answer (score 1):

Можно пометить нужный конструктор атрибутом [ImportingConstructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importingconstructorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Только контейнер должен содержать и аргумент и сам плагин.

Например:

```
[Export(typeof(ILogger))]
class Logger : ILogger {}

[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
class Plugin : IPlugin
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Plugin(ILogger logger)
    {
    }
}
```

Каталог:

```
var catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(Plugin), typeof(Logger));
```